# How to remove seekbar from VideoView Controller?

Tags: android, android-video-player

In my application i am displaying a video from a remote server. Everything is working fine. I use following code in .xml file for VideoView.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</VideoView>
```

Following is my code to play the video,

```
video.requestFocus();
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(ClipPath));
video.setMediaController(new MediaController( SubmitClipActivity.this) );
video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
{
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        video.start();
        if ( video.isPlaying() )
        {
            MyProgressDialog.Dismiss();
        }
    }
});
video.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() 
{
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
    {
        MyProgressDialog.Dismiss();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that whenever the activity get's visible it shows a seekbar below the video just like following image,

[image: Seekbar]

I just want, not to show the bottom's seekbar. is it possible to hide it ? I have already tried VideoView's `setClickable()` & `setScrollContainer()` method but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [`MediaController`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) class. If you want to provide custom controls, you can extend the class and provide your implementation. 
Use `VideoView's` [`setMediaController`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setMediaController(android.widget.MediaController)) method to assign the user defined controls. You can use `videoView.setMediaController(null);` to hide the `MediaController` altogether. [Search this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+MediaController) for more information on `MediaController`.

Comment: I do not see where you are setting the MediaController to null.

Comment: i put this line `video.setMediaController(null);` after the findviewbyid method .

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if (controllerCreated == false) {
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        mc.show();
        controllerCreated = true;
    }
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: `videoView.setMediaController(mc); ` , this will display seekbar but my requirement is not to display this seekbar dear